# How to determine if file path is absolute or relative in ColdFusion 

Tags: coldfusion

I have a function that accepts a file path. Users can pass in either an absolute or relative path to a file. If a relative path is provided, the `ExpandPath` function can convert it to an absolute path like so:

```
<cfset filepath = ExpandPath("data/test.txt") >
```

.. and it returns:

```
C:\www\example\data\test
```

But if user provides an absolute path like:

```
<cfset filepath = ExpandPath("C:\www\example\data\test") >
```

.. it returns:

```
C:\www\example\C:\www\example\data\test
```

How may I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test the string and see if it starts with C:\ for windows or \\ for unix, and use that as an if?
This could be your windows check:

```
<cfif reFindNoCase("[a-zA-Z]:\\",myFileLocation)>
   <!--- Is a absolute path --->
<cfelse>
   <!--- Is not an absolute path --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: If you're doing reFindNoCase you don't need to specify both cases in the regex! Also, it is perfectly valid to supply CF with `C:/` on Windows. So you'd want to use `[a-z]:[\\/]` if doing it this way. (Though I'd be more inclined to use  Al's method.)

Answer (score 7):

A possibly more flexible way to do this is to check to see if the directory from the raw input exists and, if not, try expandpath. Something like this:

```
<cfif directoryExists(myFileLocation)>
  <cfset theDirectory=myFileLocation)>
<cfelseif directoryExists(expandPath(myFileLocation))>
  <cfset theDirectory=expandPath(myFileLocation)>
<cfelse>
  <cfthrow message="Invalid directory!">
</cfif>
```

Comment: I believe modern CFML allows for relative paths in `directoryExists()` now.